# rxcpp: Automatically unsubscribe when out of scope

Tags: c++, rxcpp

Although `rxcpp::composite_subscription` has a method `unsubscribe` but it doesn't call it on destruction.

Does rxcpp library contains a class that automatically calls `unsubscribe` when the object goes out of scope?

Comment: This is a weak subscription, you don't have to care of unsubscription.

Comment: Can you please explain what weak subscription is?

Comment: 10 years later but I end up here somehow. What @S.M. says is that it acts a WeakPointer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the subscription does not call `unsubscribe()` in its destructor is because it is a cancellation handle, not a RAII object. subscription objects are allowed to be copied and are allowed to be discarded.

If the subscription destructor unsubscribes than discarding the subscription would cancel the work. This is not the contract for a subscription. Keeping the subscription alive does not keep the work alive and discarding the subscription does not stop or destroy the work (this is the weak lifetime that was mentioned correctly in the comments)

The real issue here is that rxcpp modeled lifetime the same way as other rx libraries. Those libraries use GC to manage lifetimes.

A new library is being built that has changes to support structured-concurrency and non-GC lifetime. There are talks and papers by Lewis Baker and Eric Neibler that explain the `Single` form. The classic rx sequence of values is being prototyped right now.